# Cant reading json variables trough rest api

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, api, rest

I have a problem reading a variable json trough a rest api

The problem:
my Json
.....

"Featured_media": 11661,
"Comment_status", "open"
"Ping_status", "open"
"Geolocation_city": [ "Oeiras"],
"_links": {
"Self": [{
"Href": "http: \ / \ / website.com \ / wp-json \ / wp \ / v2 \ / listings \ / 11660"
.....

I can read all variables less geolocation_city with this code

```
        $.getJSON('http://imaginocharme.com/wp-json/wp/v2/listings/11660', function (jd) {

        $('#stage').html('<p> Nome: ' + jd.featured_media + '</p>');
        console.log(jd.featured_media);
        $('#stage').append('<p>Descrição : ' + jd.comment_status + '</p>');
        console.log(jd.comment_status);
        $('#stage').append('<p>Nome : ' + jd.ping_status + '</p>');
        console.log(jd.ping_status);
        $('#stage').append('<p>Cidade : ' + jd.geolocation_city + '</p>');
        console.log(jd.geolocation_city);
        $('#stage').append('<p>Links : ' + jd._links.self[0].href + '</p>');
        console.log(jd._links.self[0].href);

           });
```

My console log

```
11661
index.html (29,29)
open
index.html (31,29)
open
index.html (33,29)
undefined
index.html (35,29)
http://imaginocharme.com/wp-json/wp/v2/listings/11660
index.html (37,29)
```

I've tried several ways to read the variable geolocation_city and always gives undefined

Can anyone help?
Any idea?

Comment: are you sure, the capital case/small case variable names are not the problem?

Answer (score 0):

jd.geolocation_city is an array, that's why you don't have it displayed. Try this instead:

```
jd.geolocation_city.toString()
```

Comment: Can you console log jd.geolocation_city?

console.log( jd.geolocation_city );

Comment: return

    ReferenceError: jd is not defined
       at <anonymous>:2:1
       at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:878:140)
        at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:811:34)
        at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:667:21)
       ReferenceError: jd is not defined ...

Comment: Did you do in inside function (jd) {} ?

Comment: Yes, at the end ` $.getJSON('imaginocharme.com/wp-json/wp/v2/listings/11660';, function (jd) { $('#stage').html('<p> Nome: ' + jd.title.rendered + '</p>'); $('#stage').append('<p>Descrição : ' + jd.content.rendered + '</p>'); $('#stage').append('<p>Nome : ' + jd.slug + '</p>'); $('#stage').append('<p>Cidade : ' + jd.geolocation_city + '</p>'); $('#stage').append('<p>Links : ' + jd._links.self[0].href + '</p>'); console.log(jd.geolocation_city) });`

Comment: Semicolon is missing at the end of log. Should be: console.log(jd.geolocation_city);

Comment: when i use jd.geolocation_city.toString() return

  'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined'